# Custom image processing

Tags: image, image-processing

Is there any image processing library in linux to create image like this?[image]

Comment: Like what? Do you want to add the name, month, just the layout etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in Imagemagick using the montage function. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/.

```
montage -label "%t" January.png February.png ... December.png -title "2018 Calendar" -tile 3x4 -geometry +10+10 result.png
```

If using Imagemagick 7, add magick before montage.